# Run a single test in Gallio multiple times

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid, gallio, parallel-testing

Is there a way to run a single test case multiple times (automatically) in Gallio?

At this point in time, I have everything set up and parallel tests running correctly.  The problem is I want to run the same test in parallel with itself, in theory, all I need to do (since the test is already set up to run in parallel) is get the test to run multiple times.

I am using Selenium Grid with a node per test case and Gallio to run my C# Selenium webdriver test cases.